# lowest loop vs intermediate methods call

Tags: java

I'm writing an API which works like this.

```java
method0() {
}

method1() {
    // invoke method0 in predictable times
}

method2() {
    // invoke method1 in M/n times or invoke method0 in M times?
}
```

Say, I know how exactly many times `method0` going to be invoked through `method1()`, do I have to invoke `method0` in `M` times? or invoke `method1` in `M/n` times?

Does intermediate method call which is related with call stack push/pop can be a performance problem?

Sorry for my poor English. And Thanks in advance.

```java
int read08() {
}

int read16() {
    return (read08() << 8) | read08();
}

int read32_1() {
    return (read16() << 16) | read16();
}

int read32_2() {
    int value = 0x00;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= read08();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a case of premature optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always favour readability over premature optimisation. So, go ahead and write your method in the most readable fashion.

If your final system performance is unsatisfactory, and [robust benchmarking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html) shows this area of your code is a bottleneck, do some further testing to see which option is faster.

Comment: In your particular example, I find `read32_1()` more readable. My main suggestion is to concern yourself with what is readable and maintainable. Only worry about what is efficient when you are forced to improve performance *and* you can prove this area is a bottleneck.